# elongate or scale limbs of a model in XNA

Tags: xna

I'd like to create one model that I import into an XNA game.

I'd like to be able to copy this model and make programmatic modifications to it during execution (with the intent of using the same model to represent multiple characters in the game).  For example, I'd like to make the legs slightly longer or shorter, or the waist slightly fatter or thinner, or the head slightly smaller or larger.

I know how to use transforms to modify a mesh, but it seems that what I need here is to apply a transform to only a subset of vertices in that mesh.  I have no idea how to do this in XNA, or if it's even supported.

Two questions:
1) is functionality like this supported in XNA?
2) if so, what kind of methods are used to obtain the desired result?

Comment: Seems like something you could do with the right bone transformations on a model (that has been appropriately set up for this). Asking on gamedev.stackexchange.com might get you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called `retargeting`. You want to have multiple `skeleton`s but a single `model`.

Using skeletal animation, each bone affect the vertices of the `model` using weights, which is called `skinning`. If you have different skeletons, the model stays the same but the way its vertices are transformed change.

Short answers to your question:

1. No. But there might exist projects to help you along the way.
2. It will depend on what solution you're trying to use. It will both affect the way the characters are animated, exported and played back in the engine.

This this question on [stackexchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27058/how-to-programatically-retarget-animations-from-one-skeleton-to-another) or [this project](http://www.digitalrune.com/Products/GameEngine/Animation.aspx) for more information.

I have never attempted to do this in XNA though, only "commercial game engines".